# Automatically Sort Table By Ascending Quantity in Php/html, not sql

Tags: php, html, wordpress, sorting

I have data, from HTTP requests, that I am rendering in the form of a table. Right now, I just have it so that the listings are ordered as the for loop processes them, but I want it so that the for loop processes them and then sorts the data according to highest % of weight. Weight is a column header in a table wit h7 other column headers.

Now, this project is in php + html. I have never used php before, so am rather confused with syntax and where to put logic.

I have tried using the sort() and asort() functions in php, but I am clearly putting these things in the wrong order. I feel like what I want to do is: 1) save the output of the for_loop that renders the table in a table format as some data type 2) then sort that data type according to the column of weight in ascending order. 3) display this in a table

Here is some code!

```
                    "<div class='last-updated text-left'>" .
                        "<small>As of <span>$update_date</span></small>" . 
                    "</div>" .
                    "<table class='ershares-table with-thead'>" .
                    "<thead><tr>" . 
                        "<th>Company</th>" . 
                        "<th>Weight</th>" . 
                        "<th>Ticker</th>" . 
                        "<th>Market Price</th>" . 
                        "<th>Shares Held</th>" . 
                        "<th>Market Value</th>" . 
                        "<th>CUSIP</th>" . 
                    "</tr></thead> " . 
                    "<tbody>";
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $for_loop_limit; $i++) : 
                            echo 
                                "<tr>" . 
                                    "<td><strong>" . $ers_holdings[$i]["securityDescription"] . "</strong></td>" .
                                    "<td>" . getMarketValuePercentage($ers_holdings[$i]["securityIdentifier"], $ers_holdings[$i]["marketValuePercentage"]) . "%</td>" . 
                                    "<td>" . $ers_holdings[$i]["ticker"] . "</td>" . 
                                    "<td>" . $ers_holdings[$i]["marketPriceOfSecurity"] . "</td>" . 
                                    "<td>" . $ers_holdings[$i]["sharesHeldOfSecurity"] . "</td>" . 
                                    "<td>" . $ers_holdings[$i]["marketValueOfHolding"] . "</td>" . 
                                    "<td>" . $ers_holdings[$i]["securityIdentifier"] . "</td>" . 
                                "</tr>";
                        endfor;
                    echo "</tbody>" . 
                '</table>' .
```

I want to sort the table by having the highest value for `getMarketValuePercentage...` at the top. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `usort()`.

Before doing your `foreach` loop, you'll call something along the lines of:

```
usort($ers_holdings, function ($a, $b) {
    return ($a['securityIdentifier'] <=> $b['securityIdentifier']);
});
```

which would sort the data in `$ers_holdings` based on the `['securityIdentifier']` value.

Comment: Thank you so much, but how do I associate this with the table that gets display? Sorry for my ignorance! First time working with tables and php.

Comment: @raki or is that exactly what it’s doing?

Comment: Well, the entire block of code you showed could be described or summed up as "Product some html that results in a html `<table>` based on the data in array `$ers_holdings`". All the `usort()` does is (re)order the entries in that array.

Comment: Since your `foreach`-loop just iterates over the `$ers_holdings` array, in the order it happens to be in, sorting it ahead of time results in the html `<table>` being in that same order. So sorting the array, results in a similarly-sorted `<table>`.

Comment: it doesn’t sort, but I’m thinking it may be conflict because securityIdentifier is used for two columns, not just the one we want sorted by

Comment: I tried replacing with marketValuePercentages and no change. The table still isn’t getting sorted according to the weight column.

Comment: Yea, i'm not sure what is actually inside that array as the code that produces it wasn't included. Try running `var_dump($ers_holdings);` or `echo nl2br(var_export($ers_holdings, true));` to see whats actually in there. prior to the `sort` and `foreach` code.

Comment: It's a mistake to keep referring to the `weight` column though, infact a mistake to think about tables/columns at all (even though that is the eventual desired outcome). Tables can exist in SQL and HTML (which can be interacted with by php indirectly), but you're not dealing with tables in PHP. You're dealing with a multidimensional array here.

Comment: Maybe just add the output of either the `var_dump` or `var_export` to your initial question, then i could give a more direct answer.